# Is it possible to delete folders in Blender's file view?

Tags: file-browser

It's possible with files (right-click, `x` key, click "Delete" to confirm), but I haven't gotten it to work with directories yet. In case it changes anything, I'm using Blender 2.67b on Debian 7.0.

Comment: Could somebody please add the tags 'directory' (or 'folder') and 'delete'? (I don't have enough rep).

Comment: no need for those tags.

Comment: All right then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to to delete directories in Blender's file browser, unfortunately.

Comment: Because it's not implemented yet... ? :)

Comment: @ForestKa i wouldn't assume that, probably because it might do more harm than good or security reasons etc.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I can't think of any security reasons (other than deleting important folders). Maybe when you're naming a new folder and hit "Escape" it should cancel instead of creating a folder named "New Folder".